# How to offset the biggest slice automatically in google pie chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart

How can I find and offset the biggest slice **automatically** using google pie chart?

[image: google chart offset the biggest slice]

In this example it should be the language Hindi with 300 millions speakers.

*Basically, I have to loop through the data and return the index of the highest entry. Is there a faster way than a loop?*

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
    ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
    ['Dogri', 2.3], ['Gujarati', 46], ['Hindi', 300],
    ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
    ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
    ['Marathi', 72], ['Nepali', 2.9], ['Oriya', 33],
    ['Punjabi', 29], ['Sanskrit', 0.01], ['Santhali', 6.5],
    ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Indian Language Use',
    legend: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    slices: {  5: {offset: 0.1}
            }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: You're dealing with a 22 item array.  Even the most inefficient loop will not be at all expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizing the API, you can use the [`getSortedRows() method`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getSortedRows).

`data.getSortedRows([{column: 1, desc: true}])` will return the sorted array of row IDs.  index `0` will be the largest one.  Then it's a simple matter of applying that to your `options` variable:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
    ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
    ['Dogri', 2.3], ['Gujarati', 46], ['Hindi', 300],
    ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
    ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
    ['Marathi', 72], ['Nepali', 2.9], ['Oriya', 33],
    ['Punjabi', 29], ['Sanskrit', 0.01], ['Santhali', 6.5],
    ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Indian Language Use',
    legend: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    slices: {}
  };
  options.slices[data.getSortedRows([{column: 1, desc: true}])[0]] = {offset: 0.1};

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: One thing I realized is, that this method overwrites all settings for the matched slice (eg. [custom colors](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/2m4gm61n/)). How to I just add the offset as an additional parameter?

Comment: Okay that was more basic js question as I though. I just replaced the line with `options.slices[chartdata.getSortedRows([{column: 1, desc: true}])[0]].offset = 0.1;` (eg. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/2m4gm61n/2/))

Answer (score 0):

If you want the option to offset more than one slice, .getSortedRows will only be part of the solution. Here's some code that will allow multiple slices too:

```js
 google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
    ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
    ['Dogri', 2.3], ['Gujarati', 46], ['Hindi', 300],
    ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
    ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
    ['Marathi', 72], ['Nepali', 2.9], ['Oriya', 33],
    ['Punjabi', 29], ['Sanskrit', 0.01], ['Santhali', 6.5],
    ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Indian Language Use',
    legend: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    slices: {}
  };
  arr=data.getSortedRows([{column: 1, desc: true}]);
  obj={};
  t = document.getElementById("topCount").value;
  for (k in arr) {
    if(k<=t-1){ // get top k+1 languages
      obj[arr[k]]={offset: 0.2};
    }
  }   
  options.slices=obj;
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<body>
most popular languages: 
<select id="topCount" onchange="drawChart()">
  <option value="1">top</option> 
  <option value="2">top 2</option> 
  <option value="3">top 3</option> 
  
</select>  
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```